# Recorrer un vector y que compare un numero aleatorio

Tags: java

Cuando entra al vector y el numero no esta en el arreglo me muestra "no gano parcero" las 12 veces que recorre el vector.Quiero que solamente me muestre una sola vez el no gano y me siga haciendo el resto de instrucciones

```
int azar = (int) (Math.random() * 38 + 0);

int[] veinticincos = {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36};

 for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
     if (azar == veinticincos[i]) {
         System.out.println("Usted gano y su numero es" + azar);           
     } else {
         System.out.println("no gano parcero");           
     }
 }
```

Comment: Con Java 8 podría validar `if(IntStream.of(veinticincos).anyMatch(num -> num == azar)) System.out.println("Usted Gano") ;`w

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con esto.

```
String mensaje = "no gano parcero";
for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    if (azar == veinticincos[i]) {
        mensaje = "Usted gano y su numero es" + azar;
        break;           
    }
}
System.out.println(mensaje);
```

Comment: compadre muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: De nada y ayudame marcando la respuesta como correcta para cerrar la pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes probar con esto

```
int azar = (int) (Math.random() * 38 + 0);

int[] veinticincos = {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36};


int a=0;

 for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {

     if (azar == veinticincos[i]) {
         System.out.println("Usted gano y su numero es" + azar); 
         a=1;          
     } 
 }

 if(a==0){

 System.out.println("no gano parcero"); 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

Prueba a transformar tu array en una lista y utilizar la función contains para comprobar si el número generado está en la lista. EL código quedaría así:

```
int azar = (int) (Math.random() * 38 + 0);

        Integer[] veinticincos = {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36};

        List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(veinticincos);

        if (lista.contains(azar)) {
                 System.out.println("Usted gano y su numero es" + azar);           
        } else {
                 System.out.println("no gano parcero");           
        }
```

Integer "es un objeto para los valores de tipo int". Es necesario ya que las listas no pueden ser de tipo primitivo.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo.